# Rackspace for Django Hosting

Tags: python, django, rackspace

I am working on a project right now and I am looking for hosting solutions that might fit for it.
The project is written in Django.
I was looking at rackspace and liked it a lot from its ideas and their "fanatical" support.

Does anyone have any experience on hosting Django at Rackspace.
The setup would involce something around 5 servers.

One Load Balancer.

Two Web.

One Database.

and maybe some monitoring and extra stuff, memcache on onother one

How easy it is to set something like this up from a perspective based on rackspace features.
I know my way around unix etc well enough.
Is there away to use racspace cloud files for djangos site media storage, uploads by users etc.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Their "fanatical" support is a farce; if you want to do everything their way they'll screw it up and make life hard for you; if you want to do it your own way they'll screw it up and make life hard for you (and charge you a fortune for the privilege).

There are better *and* cheaper hosting companies out there, and plenty of them.  I'd strongly recommend finding one of them.

Comment: any recommendations? scalability is important...

Comment: Server Fault isn't a shopping site.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/292013/good-sites-for-discussing-specific-hosting-provider-server-specification-scenario

Comment: oh arlgiht, i wasn't aware of that, ill check out some other places and see if i can get some information